# Separate tables or differentiating fields?

Tags: mysql

I have two websites that I run that are both a subscription-based service. Both of the sites allow the subscribers to make "subusers" that can use their subscriptions but have a different login (for security and logging purposes). Each website has a different way of implementing this.

**Separate Table**

The first system has a separate table called `subsusers`. Each subuser is linked (via foreign key) to a `user`. This setup requires additional code in the login scripts as well as anywhere user info needs to be accessed.

**Differentiating Fields**

The other site does not have a `subusers` table. Instead, a field in the `users` table points to another user as its "parent", signifying that it is a subuser. This requires less coding in login and user info scripts.

Both of these setups are fully functional and work fine. I am wondering though: What are the advantages and disadvantages of each (speed, coding, hassle)?

Comment: You should change your question to "what are the advantage of one versus the other" because there is not always a "better" solution. Only pros and cons.

Comment: Good point. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Pros:

1. If you set up your keys correctly, you can implement cascading deletes/updates more easily. If your users cancels, for example, deleting them will automatically delete the other users, via the foreign key. If you need to update a user account and have those changes affect all their subusers, that's also very straightforward here
2. If the data requirements between users and subusers are substantially different, you could avoid a lot of unused fields that would otherwise be required in a one table solution

Cons:

1. Basically everything you described and
2. What happens if a subuser becomes a user? Or a user becomes a subuser? How do you keep the application logic tidy users are members of both the user table and the subuser table?

**Option 2:**

Pros
 1. It's easier to manage the type of scenario described above, where a user might become a subuser or vice versa.

2. The application logic is simple and straightforward, especially if you don't have several levels (sub-subusers and sub-sub-subusers, for example)

Cons

1. If you do have multiple levels (and especially if you have an variable number of levels) this can get to be kind of pain
2. If your user data and subuser data are radically different and you find yourself inserting a ton of null values for every user and subuser, this is probably a good indication that the schema needs to be changed (either with a user-subuser setup, or perhaps something else, like separating user meta from users, and so forth)

Between the two, if it were me, I'd probably choose option 2. It's cleaner, in a lot of circumstances, and you probably don't have several levels and/or an unknown number of levels. If both of those statements are true, it will likely be easier for you to maintain option 2, as opposed to option 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are only two levels (user and subsuser), and the data is pretty much exactly the same, so option 2 is the best option.